# office interopt on servers without ms office installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Office interop means that your software communicates with Office and operates it through the Interop API. Not installing Office on the server is the problem you are facing: it can't find the classes in the registry it needs to communicate with.

There is an underlying, even bigger problem though: you should never use Office in a hosted environment.

From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Comment: Thanks for the info. However what I intend to achieve is to read an excel file data into a grid and work with the data offline.

Comment: @OtaighoVictor - You may wish to look into EPPlus which is a library for working with Excel files.

Comment: Agreed, I would use EPPlus instead.  It should not require major refactoring of the existing code.